# HTML Error Message will be returned instead of the custom JSON error message

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I have an API_1 that I call with Postman. If there is an error in the calculation, an error message will be output in JSON format, as well as the status code. I use the following code for this:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_default_error(e):
    message = e.description
    return jsonify(error=message), e.code
```

The output in Postman looks like this:
[image]

This is the correct JSON error message that will be returned.

My goal is that API_1 is called by API_Total. If I now call API_Total with Postman, which then calls API_1 and an error occurs there in the calculation, the JSON error message should normally be passed from API_1 to API_Total, and then output by API_Total. However, I get the following output:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Error response</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error response</h1>
    <p>Error code: 400</p>
    <p>Message: Bad Request.</p>
    <p>Error code explanation: 400 - Bad request syntax or unsupported method.</p>
</body>
```

But I don't want the JSON error message to be replaced by an HTML error message.

```
return jsonify(error=message), e.code, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Unfortunately, this does not change anything and there is still no JSON error message.

```
#Simplified procedure


#1. Postman calls API_Total
@app.route('/api/API_Total', methods=['GET'])


#2. API_1 is called by API_Total
@app.route('/api/API_1', methods=['GET'])
      ....

    try:
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers_content, data=payload_content, proxies=proxies)
    except:
        return None
        
        
#3. API_1
    #Performing the calculations
    #If an error occurs:
    return abort(404, 'Bad Request')
    #app.errorhandler is called
    @app.errorhandler(Exception)
    def handle_default_error(e):
        message = e.description
        #Return to API_Total
        return jsonify(error=message), e.code



#4 When an error occurs, API_Total displays it as HTML rather than JSON unless I set the Status Code to 200.
```

This is where I have the problem (#3). If I return it using jsonify and do not set the status code to 200, the error message is output as HTML. But if I use return jsonify and set the status code to 200, the error message is correctly output as JSON. But I get the error message and the status code using abort. I would also like to return the status code correctly and not set it to 200 by default.

Comment: How does API_Total  call API_1???

Comment: I have added it to the description above

Comment: Thank you, now headers_content and payload_content too.

Comment: Actually it might be that `return abort` that returns the Error response you're seeing.

Comment: I have added some more information

Comment: If possible try to post a single file minimal code that people can use to reproduce the error just by copying and pasting. I know more django than flask but if I have something to run like `flask –app myApp run` I can try to help you, maybe while trying to reduce the code toa single file you'll find the error yourself.

Comment: I have tried to show the code in a simplified way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work for you:

```
 # Customize error responses based on the exception type
 if isinstance(e, ValueError):
     error_message = "ValueError: " + error_message
     error_code = 400  # Bad Request

 return jsonify({"error": error_message}), error_code
```